# i can't find the left/right wheel topic on turtlebot Kobuki?

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, the "/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop" topic controls linear velocity and angular velocity of the turtlebot kobuki, what i have been trying to find is the topic that controls the rotational speed of the left/right  wheel of the turtlebot kobuki in order to implement an LQ regulator to control the speed loop of the turtlebot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283692/i-can%27t-find-the-left/right-wheel-topic-on-turtlebot-kobuki-?/) by [C3pO](https://answers.ros.org/users/33868/c3po/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without knowing more about your system (packages, real vs. simulated, topics, etc.) it's hard to give a precise answer. I'm guessing that the `/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop` topic takes `Twist` messages which means that there *isn't* a separate topic for left and right motors (if that's what you're looking for). Here is the definition of a `Twist` message

```
$ rosmsg show geometry_msgs/Twist
geometry_msgs/Vector3 linear
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
geometry_msgs/Vector3 angular
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
```

As you can see, there's `linear` and `angular` components to the message. The ones that are probably used are the `linear.x` (forward/backward) and the `angular.z` (rotate clockwise/counterclockwise). There is no component for individual wheel speeds (if that's what you're looking for). You can get around this by doing some math to determine the correct `linear`/`angular` component values and publish those values along the correct topic.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [C3pO](https://answers.ros.org/users/33868/c3po/) on 2018-02-26**:
there is an internal regulator to assure that the Turtlebot goes the exact speed set by the *"cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop" topic.( they use PID regulator for that)
for more accurate measurement i want to use LQ regulator, and for that a separate topic for left and right motors is necessary.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-26**:
What I'm saying is that that's probably not exposed. I can only guess with the information given.

**Comment by [C3pO](https://answers.ros.org/users/33868/c3po/) on 2018-02-26**:
it is kind of important for my work, i guess i will just keep looking, thank you :)

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-07**:
@C3pO if this answered your question then please click on the check mark to mark the answer as correct.

**Comment by [C3pO](https://answers.ros.org/users/33868/c3po/) on 2018-03-08**:
i ran the rqt_graph during the simulation and i think you are right, the left/right motor topic is not accessible. i will simply try to improve the PID parameters instead of using a different regulator. Thank you for your help